# melt the lower half from systematic matrix in R

Tags: r

Given that I have a three by three systematic matrix.

```
> x<-matrix(1:9,3)
> x[lower.tri(x)] = t(x)[lower.tri(x)]
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    4    5    8
[3,]    7    8    9
```

Then I apply library `reshape2` to make it in long-format.

```
> library(reshape2)
> x <- melt(x)
> x
  Var1 Var2 value
1    1    1     1
2    2    1     4
3    3    1     7
4    1    2     4
5    2    2     5
6    3    2     8
7    1    3     7
8    2    3     8
9    3    3     9
```

As the upper diagonal and bottom diagonal are identical, I only need half of result, which will look like below.

```
Var1 Var2 value
   1    1     1
   2    1     4
   3    1     7
   2    2     5
   3    2     8
   3    3     9
```

Any elegant approach to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the values for the bottom or upper half to NA, and then `melt` ignoring missing values, assume there are not missing values in the matrix originally or you don't need to keep them in the result if there are:

```
x[upper.tri(x)] = NA
reshape2::melt(x, na.rm=T)

#  Var1 Var2 value
#1    1    1     1
#2    2    1     4
#3    3    1     7
#5    2    2     5
#6    3    2     8
#9    3    3     9
```

Comment: Or the more confusing version: `reshape2::melt(\`is.na<-\`(x, upper.tri(x)), na.rm = TRUE)` or `x %>% \`is.na<-\`(upper.tri(.)) %>% melt(na.rm = TRUE)` for pipers. This way preserves `x`, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 1):

As the 'x' was already assigned and `melt`ed, we can get a logical index of the non-duplicate rows after `sort`ing the subset of dataset with 1st and 2nd column by row and then use it to subset the rows

```
x[!duplicated(t(apply(x[1:2], 1, sort))),]
#     Var1 Var2 value
#1    1    1     1
#2    2    1     4
#3    3    1     7
#5    2    2     5
#6    3    2     8
#9    3    3     9
```